# Javascript if statement issue: No display in the webpage

Tags: javascript, html, syntax

I have a VERY BASIC knowledge of javascript and I was looking forward to learn some conditional statement in javascript. So I went on and entered this code in a HTML file called "index.html":

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>A sample webpage</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the result that came was completely normal. A title called "Sample Webpage" appeared.

But the next code what I entered created problems in the result,

```
var myNumber = window.prompt("Enter number: ");
parseFloat(myNumber);
document.write(myNumber);
```

The result comes as expected.

```
if (myNumber > 15) {
    document.write(<p>Good! You've passed! </p>);
}
else {
    document.write(<p>You failed! Try again next time.</p>);
}
```

But when I add this if statement which gives an output based on the user's input, I get a blank page. I don't understand what is the reason for this. Are there any problems in the syntax?

It also seems to me that it doesn't execute the first part of the code I've written, it completely wants all of the code. I feel this is normal but doesn't it have to actually execute the "document.write" code?

Comment: Why do so many beginners think `if` is a loop? A loop is something that repeats, like `while` or `for`. If you understand the English word "loop" it should be obvious, since it's something that's round.

Comment: You need `myNumber = parseFloat(myNumber);`. Functions can't reassign to their arguments.

Comment: You need to wrap your string in quotes. Also when you get a little further: NEVER use document.write after the page has finished loading. Actually never use it, just use innerHTML or textContent of some container

Comment: You are almost certainly getting an error in your browser's console when loading this page. When debugging JavaScript in browsers, it helps greatly to have the console up. Hit F12 to open developer tools on all major browsers, then click the Console tab on the top.

Comment: @mplungjan, setting `innerHTML` is also wrong. Set `textContent` when setting text, and `appendChild` when setting elements.

Comment: @junvar there is nothing wrong with setting innerHTML. If his string contains HTML, he MUST use innerHTML unless he wants to create textNodes and elements

Comment: @mplungjan, using `innerHTML` is like writing `doCalc('3+2')` instead of `add(3, 2)`. Or `car.do('change wheel and fill gas') instead of `car.changeWheel(); car.fillGas()`. It's **very** wrong.

Comment: @mplungjan OK... guess I have to quote it.. But what does it actually do then??

Comment: Ok I don't know what's going down but as I said I'm VERY basic. I understand by what you mean by innerHTML but I don't really know about textContent.. How did I even learn javascript basics without knowing these...?

Comment: document.write takes a string as argument. You pass it HTML. Just change `document.write(<p>Good! You've passed! </p>);` to `document.write('<p>Good! You've passed! </p>');` to make it work. A better approach is to add `<p id="message"></p>` to the page and where you have `document.write(<p>Good! You've passed! </p>);` you can use `document.getElementById('message').textContent='Good! You've passed!';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Way I see it, you need to quote your strings in document.write(string).
like this:

```js
if (myNumber > 15) {
    document.write("<p>Good! You've passed! </p>");
}
else {
    document.write("<p>You failed! Try again next time.</p>");
}
```

I hope it is useful for you. Thank you.

Comment: It did work! Although this doubt might have been very basic for you, thank you very much! I highly appreciate all your answers!! So I guess quotes are really important when integrating these scripts with the HTML documents.. (Also thanks to every user who had the time to reply to this doubt :D )

Answer (score 0):

document.write takes a string as argument. You pass it HTML.

Just change

`document.write(<p>Good! You've passed! </p>);`

to

`document.write('<p>Good! You've passed! </p>');`

to make it work. A better approach is to add

`<p id="message"></p>`

to the page and where you have

`document.write('<p>Good! You've passed! </p>');`

you can use

`document.getElementById('message').textContent='Good! You've passed!';`

```js
document.getElementById("myButton").addEventListener('click', function() { // when clicked
  let myNumber = window.prompt("Enter number: ");
  myNumber = parseFloat(myNumber); // convert to number from string
  document.getElementById('number').textContent = myNumber;
  const msg = document.getElementById('number'); // output container
  if (myNumber > 15) {
    msg.textContent = 'Good! You\'ve passed!' // escaping the quote
  } 
  else {
    msg.textContent = 'You failed! Try again next time.';
  }
});
// above can be written using a so called ternary:
// msg.textContent = myNumber > 15 ? 'Good! You\'ve passed!' : 'You failed! Try again next time.'
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>A sample webpage</title>
</head>

<body>
  <p id="number"></p>
  <p id="message"></p>
  <button type="button" id="myButton">Did you pass?</button>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please study the snippet at the bottom - there are some more good practices in there

Comment: If I'm right, what the code does is when the "Did you pass" button is pressed, the addEventListener is called and my code is run. You also make use of textcontent attribute. You've also elminated the use of quotes. Is it also possible to bring up a text field instead of a window.prompt command??